# Unable to find predict in the mgcv package when using rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2, predict, gam, mgcv

I am using rpy2 to communicate with mgcv pkg, to get a gam prediction.

I am able to get a gam fit by using the mgcv pkg, however when I try to use the predict method, it errors out with the error:

> NameError: name 'predict' is not defined

Following is my code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
r_mgcv = importr('mgcv')
base = importr('base')

MainDt = pd.read_csv(FileLocation, header=0)
R_MainDF = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(MainDt)

modparams = "PGOOD ~ "

for c in R_MainDF.colnames:
    if 'RAW' in str(c):
        modparams += " s (`" + c + "`) + " 

modparams = str(modparams)[:-2]
gamFit = r_mgcv.gam(ro.Formula(modparams), data=R_MainDF)
```

The lines below error out:

```
eolPred= r_mgcv.predict(gamFit,newdata=R_MainDF, type="terms")
r_mgcv.matrix(ro.NA_Character,base.nrow(R_MainDF), base.ncol(R_MainDF)-2)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says:

```
NameError: name 'predict' is not defined
```

`predict` is not found in the namespace `r_mgcv`.

Check how to find where (in which package / namespace) an R symbol is defined here:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.1.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#finding-where-an-r-symbol-is-coming-from